# How do I fix a section-by-section scrolling on the page?

Tags: javascript

I want to do section-by-section scrolling on the site. I'm not happy with the jquery option and ready-made libraries, so I decided to write my own in pure javascript. But nothing works for me. Can you tell me what's wrong?

```js
let sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slide')];
    let currentSection = 0;
    let length = sections.length - 1;

    window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (e.deltaY > 0) ? ++currentSection : --currentSection;
        if (currentSection < 0) currentSection = 0;
        else if (currentSection > (length)) currentSection = (length);
        scrollToSection(currentSection);
    });

    function scrollToSection(currentSection) {
        sections.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (i === currentSection) {
                item.scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  div {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border:3px solid red;
  }
```

```html
  <main>
    <div className='slide'>1</div>
    <div className='slide'>2</div>
    <div className='slide'>3</div>
    <div className='slide'>4</div>
  </main>
```

Comment: You could just [use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts) and ditch all the JS entirely. It's 2021, the future is now :D See [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/css-snappoints) to double-check, but it should be good to go.

Comment: Can I use CSS to jump to the next section? That's the most important thing I need.

Comment: Well, your code appears to just be concerned with the scroll wheel. The CSS takes care of that for you, yes. It also handles touchscreen scrolling and just dragging the scroll bar in a nice way that'd take hundreds of lines of JS to come close to matching.